# How to fix HTML downloading instead of image file

Tags: python, urllib, download

I'm trying to download a file from a link using urllib in Python 3.7 and it downloads the HTML file and not the Image File.

So I'm trying to receive information from a Google Form, the information is sent to a Google Sheet. I'm able to receive the information in the sheet no problem. However the Form requires an Image submission which appears in the sheet as a URL. (Example: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YCBmEOz6_l7WDQw5t6AYBSb9B5XXKTuX)

This is my code:

```
import urllib.request
import random
```

Then I create a download function:

```
def downloader(image_url):
    file_name = random.randrange(1,10000)
    full_file_name = str(file_name) + '.png'
    print(full_file_name)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_url,full_file_name)
```

I get the URL and isolate the ID of the image:

```
ImgId="https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Mp5XYoyyEfWJryz8ojLbHuZ6V0IzERIV"
ImgId=ImgId[33:]
```

Then I put the ID in a download link:

```
ImgId="https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id="+ImgId+"&export=download"
```

Which results in (in the above example) "https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1YCBmEOz6_l7WDQw5t6AYBSb9B5XXKTuX&export=download".
Next I run the download function:

```
downloader(ImgId)
```

So after this I expected the png file to be downloaded into the folder of the program, however it downloaded a html file of the **google drive log-in** page instead of an image file, or even an html file of the image. Noting that to view or download the image it requires you to be signed in to Google to download in the browser, could authorization be an issue? 
(Note: If I manually paste the download link as generated by the program into my browser it downloads the image correctly)
(P.S I'm an absolute noob, so yeah)
(Thanks in advance for any answers)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using urllib for dowmloading, use requests and get the page contents using GET rest call and then convert the response content to soup content using beautifulsoup and then point to the content which you want to download, as the download function inside html would have a download link associated with it and then send a get request again with js download.

```
import requests
import bs4
response = requests.get(<your_url>)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html5lib')
# Get the download link and supply all the necessary values to the link
# Initiate Requests again
```

Comment: From there, I think "open(full_file_name, 'wb').write(response.content)" will download the file.

Comment: Yes Bill M. That will download the contents

Comment: Unfortunately using the requests module still resulted in the HTML file being downloaded and not the image.